# Get a file from host Windows 10 into a guest Windows 95 VM VirtualBox 6.1?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I have a 32 bit program that was designed for Windows 95 that I need to run, and save a file from.

I tried all of Windows 10 various compatibility modes but the program just freezes so I have installed VM VirtualBox 6.1, installed Windows 95 as a guest and it seems to be working okay.

However, no matter what I try, I am unable to get the programs .exe file from the host (a laptop) in to Windows 95 so I can run it.

I know there is no Windows 95 guest additions available, but there are videos on YouTubes showing folks playing old games using Windows 95 in VM so it must be possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to set a shared folder in the Windows 95 VM. When you do that and then launch Windows 95, there will be a shared folder on the Windows 10 host that will allow you to place files onto the Windows 95 VM. Look at [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/) for more information.

Comment: Give VMware Workstation or Player a try, it has Win95 tools...  https://www.sysnettechsolutions.com/en/install-windows-95-vmware/